# How to create Bson Document with Null value using C# official driver?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have objects with 3 string fields Country, Province, City. They can contain null or some string name.

I wanna query all data with the exact same values.

For Example i need all data where

```
City = null,
Province = "WA",
Country = "USA"
```

I created BsonDocument:

```
var lookup = new QueryDocument
{
    {"GeoPosition.City", userLocation.City},
    {"GeoPosition.Province", userLocation.Province},
    {"GeoPosition.Country", userLocation.Country}
};
```

But null field was thrown away and document looks like:

```
{
    "GeoPosition.Province" : "WA",
    "GeoPosition.Country" : "USA"
}
```

If i'm triing to use

```
Query.EQ("GeoPosition.City", userLocation.City)
```

I have exception saying that parametr cant be null.

As i see in documentation there is no problem in building query cheking if value equals null. So that is a problem with C# driver. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Depends on the data type of your city variable. If the city variable is of type BsonValue you can use the ?? operator directly:

```
BsonValue city = null;
var query = Query.EQ("city", city ?? BsonNull.Value);
Console.WriteLine(query.ToJson());
```

If your city variable is of type string you need an extra conversion cast to make the compiler happy:

```
string city = null;
var query = Query.EQ("city", (BsonValue)city ?? BsonNull.Value);
Console.WriteLine(query.ToJson());
```

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are working with BsonDocuments and not C# classs.  Because of that, for null values, you need to use BsonNull.Value to represent null values in the database and in queries.

Comment: Have no idea how to use it in this case. Cant write something like userLocation.City??BsonNull.Value there are not of the same type.
There should be very simple way that i just dont see.

Comment: try this: Query.EQ("GeoPosition.City", BsonValue.Create(userLocation.City))

Comment: Craig, that throws an error if userLocation.City is null.