# .ToJson() ignores null values using MongoDB C# Driver

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

Using the MongoDB C# driver, the following code gives me `{ }` in the `json` variable. It seems to ignore the null value in its serialization.

```
var document = new BsonDocument{{"x", null}};
var json = document.ToJson();
```

However I want `json` to be `{ "x": null }`. Can I set some option for it to serialize null values?

Comment: BsonDocument is what is ignoring the null, but AntonioOtero's answer is correct way to solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somebody else asked something similar [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685890/how-to-create-bson-document-with-null-value-using-c-sharp-official-driver)

Basically, you have to use `BsonNull.Value`.