# Check if Field Equals Null in MongoDb C# Driver 2.0

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a very simple query for mongo:

```
db.items.find( { MyFieldName: { $exists: true, $eq: null } } );
```

Not that it needs to be explained, but it finds documents which have a `MyFieldName` and where the value of that field is `null`. It seems like this would be really simple to do with the C# driver:

```
var fieldExistsFilter= Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Exists("MyFieldName", true);
var fieldValueIsNullFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MyFieldName", null);
```

However the second filter, `fieldValueIsNullFilter`, does not build if I try to check for null. It works fine if I write `"testString"` or anything like that, but not with null.

**tl:dr; version: How do I create a filter to check if field is null in MongoDb C# driver?**

Note, I checked other answers and they recommend $exists does what I want - it does not, as per [mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists):

> When  is true, $exists matches the documents that contain the
>   field, **including documents where the field value is null**. If 
>   is false, the query returns only the documents that do not contain the
>   field.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This actually works as expected with a little modification, which depends on:

> BsonNull.Value

See this question for details: 
[How to create Bson Document with Null value using C# official driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685890/how-to-create-bson-document-with-null-value-using-c-sharp-official-driver)

So the query is:

```
var fieldValueIsNullFilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("MyFieldName", BsonNull.Value);
```

Initially, I didn't realize `BsonNull` has a `Value` property.

Comment: It is the answer, you should accept it as an answer. Nothing wrong in it.

Comment: Alright, will do. Looks like there is a two day count-down before I can accept it.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the comment above you can write like this if you have some entity (depends on the property type):

```
public class CustomEntity
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string StringProperty { get; set; }

    public DateTime? DateTimeProperty { get; set; }
}


var filterIfStringPropertyNull = Builders<CustomEntity>.Filter.Eq(o => o.StringProperty, null); // if property is string

var filterIfDatePropertyNull = Builders<CustomEntity>.Filter.Eq(o => o.DateTimeProperty, BsonNull.Value.ToNullableUniversalTime());  // if property is DateTime?
```

And so on.
It could be easier

Comment: Thanks for mentioning BsonNull.Value.ToNullableUniversalTime()